# Airtable API in HTML/JavaScript Hosted on AWS S3

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, amazon-s3, airtable

I have a webpage sitting in an AWS S3 bucket, and I want to write a JavaScript file that can connect to an Airtable base via API. Everything I see online mentions Node.js specifically (I have very little JS experience and no Node experience) -- I'm wondering if it's possible to connect to the API without Node, or if not, what I need to do to configure this?

This is the HTML file (internal.html) that's sitting in an S3 bucket (note: for now I would be fine getting the JSON from the Airtable request in a single blob and dumping it into the json-blob div):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Internal</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="json-blob" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <!-- Test cell -->
                    </div>
                </div>
        <script src="js/internal.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm unclear on what should go in the JS file (js/internal.js) that gets called in the HTML; attempting to piece things together from searching, something like `var Airtable = require('airtable');` gives me a console error that require is not defined.

Comment: you can use any language if using the RESTful endpoints. What is limited though is the SDKs that are available

Comment: @C_Ogoo can you be more specific?